# Replace a character in a jquery string

Tags: jquery, format

I have the following piece of code

```
$j('#singleDeviceMac').val().replace("/:/","");
```

this piece of code is written to remove all the colon in a string which reads as follows:

00:04:F2:1C:AC:27

However it does not seem to work.. please help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It probably needs to be global to remove all of them:

```
$j('#singleDeviceMac').val().replace(/:/g,"");
```

And since it's a regex it should be unquoted.

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/JGt3A/)

Comment: @adaneo - sorry.. the mistake was on my side.. i had committed an error somewhere else.. thanks.. this is what i was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

What does `$j` mean? Do you have a call like `$j=jQuery.noConflict()` before? Otherwise it should read like this

And you don't put the Regular Expression in Quotes, just the slashes

And of course like adaneo wrote. You need the g modificator. Without you will just replace one appearance

```
jQuery('#singleDeviceMac').val().replace(/:/g,"");
```

See this fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/uECG3/